# difference between (filename.jar) and (java -jar filename.jar)

Tags: java

I'm just wondering why is it if I type in command prompt `filename.jar` it pop a message (could not find the main class) but if I type in `java -jar filename.jar` the jar file works fine. Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

jar file is not an executable. `java -jar` is the correct way to run it.

Comment: But how come that if i double click the executable file it still pop up a message (could no find the main class)?

Comment: This answer is **incorrect**. On various operating systems (including Windows and Mac OS), jar files **are** executables and they work in exactly the same way as `java -jar`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt jar files are NOT EXECUTABLES! it can have an associated app that will launch them, but its NOT EXECUTABLES!

exactly as .txt files are not executables!

Comment: @DimaGoltsman don't redefine terms here please. *Executable* means that something can be executed in the normal manner in which files are executed on the operating system. Look here at the Oracle (formerly Sun) documentation which described **Executable** jar files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jarGuide.html

Comment: @DimaGoltsman the problem is that you answer is misleading the OP to think that it's wrong to execute the jar file as a normal executable. That's not correct - Sun/Oracle specifically designed this feature so that it's possible to do just that. The source of the OP's problem is something else.

Comment: the developer of notepad also designed a feature like that. is that mean that txt files are executables? no.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an interpreter based language u need to give the jar file as input to the interpreter to execute.

Pls correct me if i am wrong.

PS: Downvoters or editors please mention the reason..Cos of half of them just re-iterate the sentence while editing.

Comment: java is a compiler, not interpreter!

Comment: @DimaGoltsman Java is a programming language, and there exists java compilers to compile **Java** code. It's simple as that, I don't know why I'm arguing this.

Comment: because you want to scream "i won an internet argument", instead, you show your ignorance by not understanding that what i meant is that java is a compiled language.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman _"java is a compiled language"_ dont' make sense... Any programming language can be compiled. Sorry to tell that your wording is confusing. Anyway, just to tell that there is a lot of people who came here and learn programming. So if you're going to write something, write it well with the appropriate terms.

Comment: just go and read on wikipedia what is a compiled language before you make fun of yourself.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman For the most implementations yes (and actually some JVM implementations starts by interpreting the bytecode before compiling it). Anyway that does not alter my original statement which was that if you want to comment something, comment it well (is that so hard to use the right terms?).

Comment: i lost interest to that bull*** , go argue with wikipedia and a library

Comment: @DimaGoltsman Your lack of understanding is astonishing. I return you your last comment.

Comment: Hey people calm down, Just to clear things, Java is a programming language that need a Java virtual machine to run, when you're creating a project you make a class and create code in it, then when you compile the compiler create a .class file and then you need a Java virtual machine to run that .class file that the compiler created.

Answer (score 0):

`.jar` files are executable on at least Windows and Mac OS. (There are not *native* code but they have an association with the program that will be used to open them, in this case *Java*)

So if you double-click on a jar file on those operating systems, they will internally invoke java as if you typed `java -jar` with the jar file as the argument.

However, if you have multiple versions of Java installed on your computer, it is possible that double-clicking opens the jar file with a different version of Java than if you typed `java -jar` on the command line.

How this works exactly depends on your operating system so you would need to specify that in your question.

.jar files have exactly the same format as .zip files (because they are .zip files with a different extension). Inside the jar/zip file there is a file called META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and this file specifies which class should be invoked when you double-click or type `java -jar`.

It helps if you can show what is inside that file. If you have the `unzip` command installed you can show the contents of this file using:

`unzip -p`*filename*`.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Without unzip, you can extract the entire jar file and look inside META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

`jar xf`*filename*`.jar`

- Which operating system are you using?
- Do you have multiple versions of Java installed?
- What is inside the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file?

Comment: jar files are not executables as txt files are not. they just have associated program that opens them.

Comment: From a user point of view, they are executable when there is a java installed. Besides that technicality Erwin is probably right in his analysis of what the problem could be.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman that's not true. Executable files are files that can be executed. Do you think that bash scripts on Unix are not executable? Execution is built into the operating system on Unix - you use the same system call to execute a bash script as an ELF file. Are you now saying that you think that the operating system is wrong?

Comment: @Fredrik it's not just a technicality. DimaGoltsman is giving the OP the wrong impression by somehow implying that it's *wrong* to double-click on a jar file and that that's what is causing the problem. That won't get the OP any closer to the solution.

Comment: .txt files also can be executed with double click. but from a programmer point of view it not executable. from a carpenter point of view, it is

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear things, Java is a programming language that need a Java virtual machine to run, after you create a project you make a class and type some code in it, then when you compile the compiler create a .class file and then you need a Java virtual machine to run that .class file that the compiler created. The jar file is not an executable, its zipped under pkzip format, so every jar file contain an MANIFEST file where it specify the mainClass to make the ball run (run the program). To run a jar you use the `java -jar <jarfile>` command